# Keep a log of evaluated expressions

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

Sometimes I perform some calculations, export the results and a week later I notice something odd with one of the exported files. I still keep the notebooks with the calculations but sometimes certain code has been erased and replaced with other code and it's hard to trace what happened.

So I wondered: is there a way to let Mathematica generate some sort of log file that logs the input that it evaluates. I don't want output and I don't want any expansions of input in the log file for otherwise it could become very large and take too much time to generate it.

For example if I wrote and evaluated the following snippets of code

```
largedata = Import[...];
```

```
myFun[ data_, ... ] := ...
```

```
foo = myFun[ largeData ]
```

(Whoops, large output and incorrect as well... Lets redefine myFun, be sloppy with lingering definitions, names, etc...)

```
myFun[ data_ ] := ...;
foo2 = myFun[ largedata ];
Export[ ..., foo, ... ];
```

(I feel experimental and write a piece of code that should be faster but it's time for a break and I stop working on it and eventually just leave it there without evaluating)

```
myFun2[ data_ ] := ....
```

Then I would like to have a log file (either as part of the notebook or stored in a directory)
that reads

```
[In1] = largedata = Import[...]; 
[In2] = myFun[ data_, ... ] := ...
[In3] = foo = myFun[ largeData ] 
[In4] = myFun[ data_ ] := ...; foo2 = myFun[ largedata ]; Export[ ..., foo, ... ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the variable `$Pre` that is applied to every input expression before evaluation. Default is not set. If you want to stop logging, you simply say `$Pre=.` Here is what you do:

```
ClearAll[log, $Pre]
SetAttributes[log, HoldAll]
log[inp_] := (PutAppend[Unevaluated[inp], "NameOfLogFile"]; inp)
$Pre = log
```

Comment: Is there a way to define a single function, say StartLogging[ fileName_ ], that applies the procedure above and is available on startup? I tried adding ```LogInput[ fileName_ ] := 
( 
    ClearAll[ LogInputFromNoteBook, $Pre ];
    SetAttributes[ log, HoldAll ];
    LogInputFromNoteBook[ inp_ ] := ( PutAppend[ Unevaluated[inp], fileName ]; inp);
    $Pre = LogInputFromNoteBook;
);``` to the init.m file but evaluating the function does not create a file upon evaluating expressions...

Comment: There are 2 bugs: You must set the attributes of "LogInputFromNoteBook" not of "log"and you must also set the HoldAll attribute of the outer function: "LogInput"